# Android phone starts freezing when hot

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, overheating

I have a strange issue with my phone.
It's an octa core 1.7 Ghz running Android 4.4.2.

When I go outside and it's too hot, the touchscreen starts to not respond when woken from sleep (or in other words, unlocked). If I put it in sleep mode and let it rest for a while, it starts working fine again after some time.

When I return home, the phone isn't so hot and it functions normally. This problem is quite rare, though.

Is this a software or hardware problem? What can I do?

Comment: Use the app [Cpu Temp](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.yanyan.cputemp&hl=en) to record and monitor CPU temperatures. If this issue happens again, it will note the temp. and then you can post us the screenshot of corresponding apps with high temperature. Also, as *Jaskaranbir* noted, it seems to be throttling. But let's see what's causing this?

Answer (score 1):

Since there is no specification of *How* hot, I would answer based on some assumptions.

The phenomenon you face is quite normal. Whenever the temperatures of the components in the device get hot, to the point of possible hardware damage, the phone CPU goes into throttling. Have a look at this post about [thermal throttling](https://superuser.com/questions/610913/how-does-cpu-thermal-throttle-work).

Basically, thermal throttling is when the CPU of the device reduces its power (clock speed and voltage). And due to this the device starts to cool down.

When its too hot (like well around 70 degrees Celsius). This will cause the device to throttle and slow the clock speed. Which in turn causes lag (or dropped frames) this affects the whole of the device (touch screen, GPU e.c.t.) and will speed back up once normal safe operating temperatures are reached.

Thermal throttling is controlled by the kernel. SO by using a modified kernel throttling can be turned off, but is defiantly **Not** recommended. This is a feature to prevent permanent hardware damage to the device.

This also explains why your phone functions normally when it cools down since that is when the processor returns to its "normal" mode.

Comment: Ok , but why  before I didn't have this problem ? So what has changed ? Is this similar to computer CPU that may have this problem when the cooler is damaged ? Is there anything I can do ? Because when I'm out my phone is useless .

Comment: This feature was always present in your phone. You are taking it as Problem, but its actually a *Feature. This is happening because your phone gets too hot and to avoid further damage from heating, system turns off some features to let it have rest and cool down. So nothing in phone has changed, its just high temperatures that are causing this. This is similar to computers (especially modern) when processor goes too hot (doesn't necessarily have to be a missing/damaged fan/cooler, they can go way hot even if the fan/cooler is working). Every processor has thermal throttling feature these days.

Comment: Ok , my wife has another phone with the same parameters , the same android system. but doesn't have any problem when we are at the same place (out of house) , so at the same environment's temperature. And just to clarify , I don't know if the cpu temperature is to high , but I feel too hot on the back side of the phone , so I'm supposing this.

Comment: This doesn't necessarily have to be same. Does not mean that if my android phone heats, all other similar models in my area should heat the same way too. It depends on a lot of factors including background apps and tasks as well as the material of clothing the phone is lying under (for example some clothing materials absorb more heat then others). Besides that, there could be many other countless factors. So its not necessary that your wife's phone has to go the same way as well. As I already said, it all depends on when kernel decides that its time to throttle.

Comment: Ok , but I had this phone the previous summer , even with more applications than today and I had no problems. Today I have done a factory reset with only the minimal system and applications and I'm facing this problem.And the strange is that if some time the phone it's not freezing after sleep, is not freezing after even if I try with hard operations like watching a video. But if he goes to sleep , after he can repeat the freezing.

Comment: this is technically correct, but almost certainly not the reason for the symptoms he's experiencing. @tiku, do you have any apps that are using an abnormal amount of battery life/that are keeping the phone awake all the time? you can use GSAM battery monitor to check this, or the built in battery stats.

Comment: @bennnnn I've explained that I've done a factory reset . So I have only the minimal application that android 4.4.2 has by default. I have tested and no application that use abnormal amount of battery.

Comment: It can very well be caused by some default application draining power, perhaps after some update. Or it can be hardware-related - some moist might have  gotten inside the phone making it more susceptible to heat. Also having the same model as your wife doesn't mean that you have the same SoC on it - each chip is unique and what one chip can't handle, the second one in the factory row can. The sleep-wake timing can just be related to what the chip actually does when it wakes up - it's a specific process changing it's internal state. Just keep your phone cool, things should be all right.

Comment: @mikky  How can I keep it cool , when I'm out ? It's summer now and out is very hot. And after 2-3 minutes when I'm out the problem begin. But there's something that anyone from you didn't explain to me  : What is changed in the phone sine last summer ? Last summer it was ok with the same applications and almost the same environment temperatures. Does the cellphone's CPU has some special material ( like for example thermal grease on PC's CPU ?) that may be damaged ? Or something else ? Can I do something if I open the cellphone ?

Comment: And , is there any way or software to configure the Android system just to turn off the screen but not to sleep ?

Comment: I did tell you at least two possible causes, one software one hardware. If it's really as bad as you say, your phone may very well be damaged. If you open the phone then of course you *may* be able to spot a problem but unless you have some kind of specialised equipment (a microscope, electronic tester, and such), you may easily miss something. Look for loose contacts, corrosion marks and moisture ingress marks (those white stickers that turn red when moisted). Also check your battery consumption, it may just give away the troubled app.

Comment: I did the temperature test , and I think there's no problem with temperature. When the phone start freezing , the CPU temperature is about 38 (Celsius).  Is there any possibility that the android 4.4.2 may have any issue that can cause my problem ?